# Separate functionality depending on Role in ASP.NET MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, design-patterns, architecture

I'm looking for an elegant pattern to solve this problem:

I have several user roles in my system, and for many of my controller actions, I need to deal with slightly different data.

For example, take

```
/Users/Edit/1
```

This allows a `Moderator` to edit a `user`s email address, but `Administrator`s to edit a user's email address and password.

I'd like a design for separating the two different bits of action code for the `GET` and the `POST`.

Solutions I've come up with so far are:

- Switch inside each method, however this doesn't really help when i want different model arguments on the POST :(
- Custom controller factory which chooses a `UsersController_ForModerators` and `UsersController_ForAdmins` instead of just `UsersController` from the controller name and current user role
- Custom action invoker which choose the `Edit_ForModerators` method in a similar way to above
- Have an IUsersController and register a different implementation of it in my IoC container as a named instance based on Role
- Build an implementation of the controller at runtime using Castle DynamicProxy and manipulate the methods to those from role-based implementations

Im preferring the named IoC instance route atm as it means all my urls/routing will work seamlessly.

Ideas? Suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Woo, no answers. Here's my attempt at the IoC approach, I think I'll  be going with this unless anyone has any other ideas.

[Segregating Controller Logic Based on User Role in ASP.NET MVC](http://blog.muonlab.com/2010/05/19/a-method-for-segregating-controller-logic-based-on-user-role-in-asp-net-mvc/)